# Instant results in Surveymonkey for quiz

Tags: surveymonkey

Is is possible to use Surveymonkey's API to get instant results for a quiz? I'm trying to design a web application where a user answers a set of questions, it instantly displays the results, and compares them to the broader population of respondents.

Answer (score 0):

The response data is available immediately via the API. The data is raw and you will need to create any visually appealing charts or diagrams to present.

Here's the catch: you will need to be able to associate a response with the respondent to whom you're presenting the results. That requires some identifying metadata to be associated with the response. For a weblink collector, [custom variables](http://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/What-are-custom-variables-and-how-do-I-use-them) is the features which allows the addition of that metadata.

Comment: The way i imagine doing it is on a website. so it might be embedded in a wordpress post or as a popup link. Is it possible to do that wit what you suggested?